# Determine if all the zeros in a list occur at the end

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, expression-test

I have a collection of (short) lists of nonnegative integers. For each, I would like a predicate that decides if all of the zeros in the list appear at the end. For example, `{1,0,1,0}` would fail since there is a `1` after the first zero, while `{2,3,17,0,0}` would pass. I can think of a number of ways (for example, find the positions of the zeros and check that they are consecutive and that the last element is zero), but none that are particularly elegant or pleasing.

Edit: The list may have no zeros in which case it should be accepted.

Comment: What about if there are no zeroes?

Comment: In that case the list should be acceptable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Finally:

```
test5 = OrderedQ @ Reverse @ Unitize @ # &
```

---

#### slow stuff:

```
test = MatchQ[#, {Except[0] .., (0) ...}] &
```

new one, this is "only" two orders of magnitude slower than Mr.Wizard's :)

```
test3 = Length[Split[#, Count[{##}, 0] != 1 &]] <= 2 &
```

getting closer, only twice as long:

```
test4 = Length @ Split @ Unitize @ # <= 2 &
```

Comment: I tried for a while to build the appropriate pattern, but just couldn't get it right. Thanks. Can you educate me --- this is clearly useful, but why doesn't something like `{x__/;x!=0,y__/;y==0}` work?

Comment: Try `MatchQ[{1, 1, 0, 0}, {x__ /; x != 0, y__ /; y == 0}]` versus `MatchQ[{2,3,17, 0, 0}, {x__ /; x != 0, y__ /; y == 0}]`. What's up with that? That's why I assumed that pattern didn't work.

Comment: So do you understand why one returns False and the other True?

Comment: @rogerl and Kuba, you must consider that `x` in `x__` is bound to a *sequence* of values.  Observe: `Replace[{1, 1, 0, 0}, {x__, y__ /; y == 0} :> HoldForm[x != 0]]` which returns `1 != 1 != 0`.  Does this explain your confusion?

Comment: Okay, you got me. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Finally, but the you are doing pattern matching so come on. Really impressive.

Comment: Accepting this answer because a) it was first, and b) Kuba showed extraordinary perseverance.

Comment: Is the speed the same if you define `test5 = OrderedQ @* Reverse @* Unitize`?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, but for mapping multiple shor lists it is even slightly slower.

Comment: @Kuba: Thing is: Your predicate returns true, even if there is no single zero at all.

Comment: @Kuba: Ah. Sorry. Missed the edit.

Comment: @Jinxed N.p. :)

Answer (score 6):

The first pattern that came to mind:

```
p1 = {___, 0, Except[0], ___};

! MatchQ[{2, 3, 17}, p1]
! MatchQ[{2, 3, 17, 0, 0}, p1]
! MatchQ[{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, p1]
```

> ```
> True
>
> True
>
> False
> ```

I am exploring other avenues now.

---

It seems that this pattern is vastly more efficient that Kuba's superficially similar one.  As a simple example:

```
pK = {Except[0] .., (0) ...};

SeedRandom[0]

x = RandomInteger[999, 20000];

! MatchQ[x, p1] // Timing // First

MatchQ[x, pK]   // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.000219649
>
> 2.542816
> ```

Comment: Also (see edit above) I think this fails in the case where there are no zeros.

Comment: @rogerl Oops!  Okay, let me see what I can do.

Comment: @rogerl I think this already works correctly?  Could you give me an example where it does not work as desired?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct; I was forgetting about the inversion of the test. Do you have any comments on the discussion we are having in the other answer?

Answer (score 5):

For big collections of lists, this should be quick:

```
fx = With[{s = SparseArray[PadRight@#]["AdjacencyLists"]}, 
    SameQ @@@ Transpose[{Length /@ s, Last /@ Replace[s, {} -> {0}, 1]}]] &;
```

Update: Even more so:

```
fx2 = OrderedQ /@ Unitize[#[[All, -1 ;; 1 ;; -1]]] &;
```

Compare (old netbook timings... seems to clobber other answers so far...):

```
(* 100000 lists each of 20 ele *)
test = RandomInteger[{0, 100}, {100000, 20}];

Column[{
  fx2r = fx2[test]; // Timing // First,
  ww = fx[test]; // Timing // First,
  xx = ! MatchQ[#, p1] & /@ test; // Timing // First,
  test5 = OrderedQ@Reverse@Unitize@# & /@ test; // Timing // First,
  f1r = f1 /@ test; // Timing // First,
  f2r = f2 /@ test; // Timing // First,
  ww == xx == test5 == f1r == f2r == fx2r}]

(*
0.390002
0.936006
5.054432
1.638011
8.190053
8.704856
True
*)
```

Comment: Nice +1. I should really read questions more carefully :)

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[f1,f2]
f1 = With[{u = Unitize@#}, FreeQ[u[[;; Tr@u]], 0]] &;

f1 /@ {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 0}, {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 2, 3}}
(* {True, False, True, False} *)

f2 = With[{u = Unitize@#}, Times @@ N @ u[[;; Tr@u]] != 0] &;

f2 /@ {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 0}, {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 2, 3}}
(* {True, False, True, False} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two bulky yet fast compiled functions. The two functions are essentially the same, but the second one is slightly adapted to rashers test case for timing comparisons. In my previous version they were even longer, but it turns out they are faster this way.

```
cfu =
 Compile[
  {{ints, _Integer, 1}}
  ,
  Block[
   {len, zFlag, res}
   ,
   res = True;
   len = Length@ints;
   zFlag = False;
   Do[
    If[
      ints[[i]] == 0
      ,
      zFlag = True;
      ,
      If[
       zFlag
       ,
       res = False;
       Break[]
       ]
      ];
    ,
    {i, 1, len}
    ];
   res
   ]
  ,
  CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ]

cfu2 =
 Compile[
  {{int2s, _Integer, 2}}
  ,
  Block[
   {len, bigLen, zFlag, res, ints}
   ,
   bigLen = Length@int2s;
   Table[
    ints = int2s[[jj]];
    res = 1;
    len = Length@ints;
    zFlag = False;
    res = True;
    len = Length@ints;
    zFlag = False;
    Do[
     If[
       ints[[i]] == 0
       ,
       zFlag = True;
       ,
       If[
        zFlag
        ,
        res = False;
        Break[]
        ]
       ];
     ,
     {i, 1, len}
     ];
    res
    ,
    {jj, 1, bigLen}
    ]
   ]
  ,
  CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ]
```

We then have

```
Column[{fx2r = fx2[test]; // Timing // First, 
  ww = fx[test]; // Timing // First, 
  xx = ! MatchQ[#, p1] & /@ test; // Timing // First, 
  test5 = OrderedQ@Reverse@Unitize@# & /@ test; // Timing // First, 
  f1r = f1 /@ test; // Timing // First, 
  f2r = f2 /@ test; // Timing // 
   First, (jRes = cfu /@ test) // Timing // 
   First, (jRes2 = (# != 0) & /@ cfu2@test) // Timing // First, 
  ww == xx == test5 == f1r == f2r == fx2r == jRes == jRes2}
 ]
```

> ```
> 0.112896
> 0.212937
> 0.656224
> 0.256140
> 0.812663
> 1.000797
> 0.105754
> 0.059129
> True
> ```

Note: The timing can be made slightly faster by manually compiling `(# != 0) &`.

Comment: Why don't you like MMA? ;P

Comment: @Kuba just want to make a fair comparison :).

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_] := Plus @@ (Join[x, {0, 0}] /. {___, 0, r__} :> {r}) == 0

f /@ {{0, 1, 2, 3, 0}, {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 2, 3}}
(* {False, True, False} *)

SeedRandom[0]
x = RandomInteger[999, 20000];
f@x // Timing // First
(* 0. *)
```

Comment: still 7.5 times slower than my pattern and fifty times slower than Kuba's `test5`. :-/

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Let's see what I can do :)

Comment: Start compiling ;-)